# Adding 2 CPT with multiple custom taxonomies to permalinks

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks

I have two custom post types with hierarchical custom taxonomies that I'd like to add to my permalink structure.

I'd like to achieve this:

```
http://example.com/cpt1//%region%//%country%/%state%/%city%/%postname%/
```

and this:

```
http://example.com/cpt2//%region%//%country%/%city%/%postname%/
```

The `'state'` part of the permalink for CPT1, ideally, should only print if the `'region'` equals North America.

For example the custom taxonomy for region is :

```
$labels = array(
    'name' => _x( 'Regions', 'taxonomy general name' ),
    'singular_name' => _x( 'Region', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
    'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Regions' ),
    'all_items' => __( 'All Regions' ),
    'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Region' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Region:' ),
    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Region' ), 
    'update_item' => __( 'Update Region' ),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Region' ),
    'new_item_name' => __( 'New Region Name' ),
    'menu_name' => __( 'Regions' ),
);  

register_taxonomy( 'region', array( 'jazz club', 'jazz festivals' ), array(
      'hierarchical' => true,
      'labels' => $labels,
      'show_ui' => true,
      'show_admin_column' => true,
      'query_var' => true,
      'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'region' ),
) );
```

I tried this to test on the `'city'` taxonomy and hook into the permalink generation but ended up with a bunch of errors:

```
add_filter( 'post_link', 'city_permalink', 10, 3 );
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'city_permalink', 10, 3 );

function city_permalink( $permalink, $post_id, $leavename ) {
    if ( strpos( $permalink, '%city%' ) === FALSE )
                   return $permalink;

    $post = get_post( $post_id );
    if ( ! $post )
             return $permalink;

    $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'city' );  
    if ( ! is_wp_error( $terms ) && ! empty( $terms ) && is_object( $terms[0] ) )
            $taxonomy_slug = $terms[0]->slug;
    else
            $taxonomy_slug = 'no-city';

    return str_replace( '%city%', $taxonomy_slug, $permalink );
}
```

Can the filter be used for multiple custom taxonomies? Actually I'm not sure if the filter is even correct due to the errors.

Comment: *Can the filter be used for multiple custom taxonomies?* Yes. What are the errors? Also note that generating the correct permalinks is only half of it, you need the correct rewrite rules to parse those incoming links into something WordPress can query for.

Comment: Hi Milo, it's a callback function error. Here's the full message: `Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'city_permalink' not found or invalid function name in /Volumes/Data 500/hash/Sites/jazzclubjurybuild.dev/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 199`

Comment: Assuming I'm getting this as the rewrite rules are not in place? How does one do this?

Comment: the errors were actually a typo in my code, apologies. errors have gone but still need further info how to parse the rewrite rules. thanks